# Xpath python contains value

Tags: python, selenium

this is the html:

```
<select name="name1" id="id1" class="class1" size="2" ondblclick="moveoption(this.id,'atmSelezionati',this.selectedIndex);" tabindex="40">
<option value="12345|0101">12345/0101</option>
<option value="64534|0102">64534/0102</option>
```

I'm trying to select the option elements by having only for example '0101' which is a part of the value tag.

This is what I'm trying but it says `"unable to locate element":`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(option/@value,'"+ "|" + '0101' +"')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

This drop down is build using select and option tag, Please use `Selenium` **Select class** :

```
select  = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id1"))))
select.select_by_value('12345|0101')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update  :**

```
index_selection = 1
driver.execute_script(f"return document.getElementById('id1').selectedIndex = '{index_selection}';")
```

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to Select class it's very usefull, unfortunatelly, my program doesn't know the '12345' part so i have to find that element knowing only '0101'.

Comment: @lungimiranza : Please see updated code above.

Comment: i'm sorry, my html code was just an example, in reality i have thousand of options and i have to select only those who contains my 4 digit value, i don't have their indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I found this workaround:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'"+ "/" + 'your text' +"')]")
```